# Не могу перебрать в цикле элементы в js

Tags: javascript

Делаю так:

```
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("th");

    for(var i; i<list.length; i++) {
         console.log(list[i]);
    }
```

В консоли пусто и ошибок нет.

Но если прописать console.log(list); , то в консоль выводятся все th.

Почему так получается?

Comment: `i` не инициализирован, код в цикл не заходит: `var i = 0;`

Comment: вот невнимательность то( уже засыпаю , вот такую глупую ошибку допустил. Благодарю!